# Remote asterisk live call logs detail

Tags: logs, asterisk

I want to make own GUI for handling live call of asterisk. i.e. It can show the followings for live calls :

- codec used for call
- call start time
- call end time
- one field for suggesting whether call was successful or not
- call duration
- stored call failure error
- duration of call 
  Can anyone suggest me how can I get above things from remote asterisk and shows in custom GUI.Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The listed items are all read-only entries in the [Call Detail Records(CDR)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5242894).

Access to these logs is usually done though a database backend, like [MySQL](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/MySQL+CDR+Backend). How to gain access to the MySQL backend depends on the usecaes and system design, but MySQL connectors are available for several programming languages.

For a more advanced usecase you might have to look at the other interfaces, like the **Asterisk Gateway Interface (AGI)** interface.